# Can Python's psycopg2 use a password protected client certificate and key?

Tags: ssl, postgresql, python

When using psycopg2 library to connect to a Postgres server with client auth required, I have seen connection strings that look like,

```
import psycopg2
c = psycopg2.connect("host=myhost dbname=mydb sslmode=verify-full sslcert=/root/.postgresql/aa/postgresql.crt sslkey=/root/.postgresql/aa/postgresql.key")
```

Can psycopg2 handle password encrypted key files? What happens if postgresql.key is password protected? Does connect() prompt for a password to unwrap the key? Can a password to the key file be provided in the connection string?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution?